# Prove that in non-abelian group $(ab)^3=e$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ is non-abelian group and let $a,b \in G$ such that $$a^3=e \\ ba=a^2 b$$ Prove that $(ab)^3=e$.

From one side I have:
$(ab)^3 = b^3 a^3 = b^3$
and from second side I have: $(ab)^3 = (ab)(ab)(ab) = aba(ba)b = aba(a^2b)b = aba^3b^2 = ab^3$.

Hence I have that:
$b^3 = ab^3$ thus $a=e$. So now I have to show that $b^3 = e$ but I have no idea how can I make it.

Comment: Where do you get '$(ab)^3=b^3a^3$' from?

Comment: You can't get $a = e$, take $S_3$ with $a = (1 \ 2 \ 3)$ and $b = (1 \ 2)$ for a counterexample.

Comment: At first glance this looks impossible; we only have one relation in $b$ and it involves a single instance of $b$ on either side so there's no way of 'cancelling' $b$s; it seems as though we could generate a quotient of a free group by the two given relations and get a 'twisted' version of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ where $b$ corresponds to the still-free $\mathbb{Z}$ factor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not true.

Consider, in $S_3$, $a = (123)$ and $b = (12)$. $a^3 = e$ and $ba = a^2b$ are easily checked, but

$$ab = (13)$$

is a transposition, hence $(ab)^3 = ab \neq e$.